# Objective-C Reset NSView to Initial state from xib?

Tags: reset, nsview, destroy, spawn

I have an NSView with buttons and states that get altered during the course of the program. But is there a way to destroy that view and "respawn" the original one that was in the xib? I can hide and show NSView but what about destroying and recreating a specific view or restoring it to its initial state? Where every component on that view is "reset"? Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do what you're asking is to have a separate XIB for the view. Its owner would be your view controller class (subclass of `NSViewController`). You would allocate an instance of that class and initialize it with the NIB name. When you first request its `view` property, that will load the NIB with a fresh instance of the view hierarchy. You would then replace the old view with the new view in the superview's subviews and, if you're using auto layout, set the constraints appropriately.

An easy way to add the view controller class and the view XIB in one step is to do File > New > File > Cocoa class.  Set the "Subclass of" combo box to `NSViewController`. Enter the class name. Check "Also create XIB file for user interface". Click Create and where you want the files saved.

**However**, all of that said, the view should not hold state, it should reflect state. The model should hold state and the controller layer should configure the view to reflect the model, including updating it as the model is changed. So, if you've done things right, you should generally just reset your model state and that should reset your view.

Comment: Hi Ken! Thank you for the reply, The separate xib is a good suggestion but as you stated the view should reflect state and the model should reflect the state. I can go in manually and reset the state of each component when "resetting" my view but it seemed a bit tedious. I was wondering if there was just an easy solution but the answers you provided are the best way to do it. I will just reset the state of the components on the view. To clarify, a label's text might change programatically but I'd loop through all components and set them manually.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tend to use [Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) to connect my UI to my controller and, through that, my model. That way, just setting the state in my model is automatically reflected in the view.

Comment: Do you always update your view based on the state of your model? As in each frame or action you perform, you "refresh" your view to reflect that model? Or do you only do it when absolutely necessary?

Comment: The view is always updated. For example, a text field has a new value set. However, that doesn't necessarily cause a re-display every time. The text field would mark itself as needing display when its value is changed. The actual re-display wouldn't occur until the next window update (usually, the end of the current pass through the run loop).